# mysql number of records in cursor without iterating?

Tags: mysql, count, database-cursor

I am trying to write mysql procedure for below logic,

```
select id, fullname from users where fullname like concat(lastname, ' ', firstname, ' (' , middlename, '%');
```

if above query returns 0 records then

```
    select id, fullname from users where fullname like concat(lastname, ' ', firstname, '%');

.... few more queries depending upon result,
```

I am trying to write procedure mysql procedure , in that, I am using mysql cursor,

```
DECLARE user_cnt CURSOR FOR select id, fullname from users where fullname like concat(lastname, ' ', firstname, ' (' , middlename, '%');
```

now I want to check number of records in user_cursor so that I can check the condition "if  query returns 0 records then"

How can I find the number of records in mysql cursor without iterating on it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do a count before the cursor:

```
select count(*)
into @user_cnt
from users
where fullname like concat (
    lastname,
    ' ',
    firstname,
    ' (',
    middlename,
    '%'
    );
```

EDIT:
If you want to do it after OPENING the cursor, try doing:

```
OPEN your_cursor;
select FOUND_ROWS() into user_cnt ;
```

Comment: I wanted to know is there any way to count number of records in existing cursor without iterating ?

Comment: @user1191081. Try `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` after your OPEN cursor.

Comment: It would be best to suggest a solution without a cursor as a caveat statement because performance is dreadful.

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` is deprecated in MySql 8, which recommends using `COUNT(*)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Include SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your cursor select.Then on fetch use FOUND_ROWS(). It gives the number of records