# Cursor row count

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

I'm writing a function in sql.

```
BEGIN
declare len int default 0;
declare other variables;

declare myCursor cursor for *myquery*;
set len = ? // cursor's length


RETURN -1;
END
```

I need the number of rows in the cursor's result, because the continuance of the function depends on the length.

I've tried @@CURSOR_ROWS, but it gave me: "MySQL said: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'CURSOR_ROWS'"

can anyone help me?

Comment: continence? I searched _t-sql find number of records in cursor_ and the first hit told me about `@@CURSOR_ROWS`. Why don't you try using it and post back any problems.

Comment: already tried. It won't work. can you write it (the syntax) ?

Comment: Show what you tried and elaborate on "it won't work".

Comment: MySQL said: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'CURSOR_ROWS'

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168327/mysql-number-of-records-in-cursor-without-iterating

Comment: **MySQL**? That's completely different to SQL Server. I will tag with MySQL for you.

Comment: i found th answer, it works. thx @AnovaConsultancy

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
select FOUND_ROWS() into len;
```