# How to check mysql cursor result null without using a loop

Tags: mysql, function

I have a mysql function that returns a varchar value. Inside this function I have define a cursor which only gives a single value. This means in my select statement, I have taken a specific value using table primary key combination. Since I know that this cursor only return one value I don't want to add a loop to check whether the cursor return a value or not.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION PROGRAM_API_Get_Name(
        program_id_     VARCHAR(15),
        uni_id_         VARCHAR(15),
        fac_id_         VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    DECLARE degree_name_ VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE get_name_ CURSOR FOR
        SELECT program_name 
            FROM degree_program_tab
            WHERE program_id = program_id_
            AND   uni_id     = uni_id_
            AND   fac_id     = fac_id_;    

    OPEN get_name_;
    IF(!done) THEN
        FETCH get_name_ INTO degree_name_;
        CLOSE get_name_;
        RETURN degree_name_;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;

END//
```

This function gives me the following error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BEGIN              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR
>   NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;      ' at line 5   0.

If you know how to overcome this, Please help me

Comment: Do you really need a cursor?. In this case I think you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this,

`cursor.rowcount` is the solution

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION PROGRAM_API_Get_Name(
        program_id_     VARCHAR(15),
        uni_id_         VARCHAR(15),
        fac_id_         VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN

    DECLARE degree_name_ VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE get_name_ CURSOR FOR
        SELECT program_name 
            FROM degree_program_tab
            WHERE program_id = program_id_
            AND   uni_id     = uni_id_
            AND   fac_id     = fac_id_;    

    OPEN get_name_;
    IF(get_name_.rowcount>0) THEN
        FETCH get_name_ INTO degree_name_;
        CLOSE get_name_;
        RETURN degree_name_;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;

END//
```

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation ([14.6.6 Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)) about `cursor.rowcount`.

Comment: @wchiquito there isn't one. Except in reference to the MySQLConnector for python that I can see. Two things here ... (1) people would use a solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19168420) , and the (2) the smart choice is to never use a cursor for what you are doing because you aren't even iterating a loop for a hard-to-code gotta use a cursor thing. You are (if it worked) bailing out after the first row. And performance is dreadful. So the moral of the story is, use something like what wchiquito did and don't use a cursor

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid the cursor with a function as:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `PROGRAM_API_Get_Name`// 

CREATE FUNCTION `PROGRAM_API_Get_Name` (
  `program_id_` VARCHAR(15),
  `uni_id_`     VARCHAR(15),
  `fac_id_`     VARCHAR(15)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT `program_name`
            FROM `degree_program_tab`
            WHERE `program_id` = `program_id_`
            AND   `uni_id`     = `uni_id_`
            AND   `fac_id`     = `fac_id_`);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```