# Can't I refer a mysql function as a view column

Tags: mysql, function, view

I have a mysql function as follows.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION PROGRAM_API_Get_Val(
        param_     VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN

    DECLARE val_ VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE get_val_ CURSOR FOR
        SELECT param_name
            FROM tab_1
            WHERE param_id = param_;    

    OPEN get_val_ ;
    IF(get_val_.rowcount>0) THEN
        FETCH get_val_ INTO val_;
        CLOSE get_val_;
        RETURN val_;
    END IF;
    CLOSE get_val_;
    RETURN NULL;

END//
```

Now I want to create the following mysql view using the above function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW application_list_view AS
SELECT   child_param_id  id,PROGRAM_API_Get_Val(param_id)     view_col  FROM tab_2;
```

both these functions execute successfully. But when I try to execute a select statement against this view it gives me the following error.

> Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'get_name_' in field list 0.000 sec

This to create table for testing,

```
create table tab_1(param_id VARCHAR(100),param_name VARCHAR(100));
create table tab_2(child_param_id VARCHAR(100),child_param_name VARCHAR(100),param_id VARCHAR(100));
```

This is to insert values for tab_1 value

```
insert into tab_1 values ('1','pro_1'); 
insert into tab_1 values ('2','pro_2'); 

insert into tab_2 values ('1','pro_1','1'); 
insert into tab_2 values ('2','pro_2','1');
```

Comment: isn't need to close cursor if rowcount equal zero?

Comment: Yes I have to do it

Comment: You can get away with writing junk in a view and succeed with the create. Running it is a different issue.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37895784/1316440](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37895784/1316440).